# Excel If field with rounding

Tags: excel, if-statement, rounding

I'm average at Excel and this one has me stumped.

What im trying to do is calculate if a cell is 0 return a figure of 0, if the cell is greater than 0 but less than 61 (eg 60) return .15, if the cell is greater than 61 then divide the cell by 60 and round up to the next whole number eg if the cell is 86 the figure returned from the divide is 1.433 so i want that rounded to 2.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if cell=61?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your formula. Assumes your cell containing the value to be evaluated is `A2`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),IF(VALUE(A2)<=0,0,IF(VALUE(A2)<=61,0.15,ROUNDUP(VALUE(A2)/60,0)*0.15)),"0")
```

Here are the test results for all your conditions.

[image: formula-results]

Comment: Thank you thank you so close i forgot to add i need the rounded number times (*) by .15  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1>0),IF(ROUNDUP(A1/60,)<2,0.15,0.15*ROUNDUP(A1/60,)),0)
```